# Best tests or questionnaires to measure person's ability to love

Tags: social-psychology, measurement, test, big-five, love

What are the best methods (questionnaires/tests/etc) to measure ability to love?

So far I see those

1. **Light Triad** [Test](https://scottbarrykaufman.com/lighttriadscale/) ([described](https://blogs.scientificamerican.com/beautiful-minds/the-light-triad-vs-dark-triad-of-personality/) in Scientific American)
2. **Big Five** personality traits (OCEAN model) - especially its *agreeableness* subscale (friendly/compassionate vs. critical/rational)
3. HEXACO [model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HEXACO_model_of_personality_structure) of personality structure - its  *agreeableness* subscale + Honesty-Humility subscale

I realize that "love" is a very broad term, which is poorely determined, but anyway let's give it a try! At least let's try to factor out some components of love (loving person) and try to measure these separate components.

P.S. [This](https://psychology.stackexchange.com/questions/9891/how-can-we-scientifically-measure-love) question is related, but does not provide any clear tests.

Comment: I believe the other question was about the *state* of love, whereas this question appears to be about the *trait* of love.